# Subprocess.Popen argument not passing to new process

Tags: python, subprocess

musicdb[56] is "C:\\Users\\Andrew\\song.mp3"

So I'm trying to pass a song onto mplayer, it works if I quote the song like like:

```
player = subprocess.Popen(["mplayer", "C:\\Users\\Andrew\\song.mp3"], creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

but

```
player = subprocess.Popen(["mplayer", musicdb[56]], creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Doesn't work even though musicdb[56] is exactly the same string as used in the first example.

Can anyone explain why?
I can't find anything on google.

Comment: You wrote `musicdb[56] == "C:\\Users\\Andrew\\song.mp3"` instead of `musicdb[56] = "C:\\Users\\Andrew\\song.mp3"`

Comment: I simply meant that musicdb[56] was exactly that string - It's all getting read from a txt file - sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug issues like this, I use this approach:

```
cmd = ["mplayer", musicdb[56]]
print repr(cmd)
subprocess.Popen(cmd, ...)
```

Using `repr`, you can see all the odd stuff that might be hiding in an innocently looking string (like, for example, extra new line characters at the end).

Comment: That's exactly what it was!

A newline character at the end of the string.